# Query/update the datastore in android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am using the below tutorial to create entities in my datastore
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities
 I need some help in understanding how do I query the datastore in my android application. For example if I have entity Note and the endpoint NoteEndPoint created in my myproject-appengine. Then in myproject, how do I query/update the datastore for that entity in my Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

I understood it. This is accomplished using the endpointbuilder. We get endpoint object and use the inset/update/delete/list operations on the same.